# 18.04 Ubuntu Operating System does not give me a driver for Dell Mono B1160 Printer

Tags: drivers, printing, dell, 18.04

I would appreciate any help regarding installation of a working driver which will enable my Dell mono B1160 printer to operate. Too many hours I have spent trying to print from my Ubuntu computer to this Dell B1160 printer.
Thanking all who have a suggestion on the driver and installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and here's the solution:

1. Download the driver archive from [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en/en/debsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=1M4PC):
2. Unpack it and go to `~/Downloads/B1160_B1160w_UnifiedLinuxDriver_1.01/cdroot/Linux`
3. Execute the installation script `sudo sh install.sh`
4. Remove all printers from the system, including the one that was added during the installation.
5. Click `Add new printer` and choose Dell B1160 Mono Laser Printer in your printer driver settings
6. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

The Dell B1160 is actually a Samsung in disguise
https://commtechwatch.com/2012/08/the-b1160w-a-samsung-mono-laser-in-dells-clothing/

So in CUPS just choose the printer as Samsung ML2165
Worked for me on Raspbian

Answer (score 0):

Before I could get the `install.sh` script to succeed I had to comment out the following two lines in the `start_install.sh` script like so:

```
#. "$SCRIPT_DIR/check_packages.sh"
#MISSING=`check_required_packages required_packages`
```

The problem is that it can't find `libsane` even though I installed it I guess because Ubuntu 18.04 appears to have new directory structure for so libraries that their `check_packages.sh` script doesn't understand.

Like the answer by @xpoback after installation completed I also had to remove the printers added by the install script and click the add button in the user interface to add it again before it started working.