# How to get Dell B1165nfw scanner working in 18.04?

Tags: drivers, dell, 18.04, scanner

I finally got my Dell B1165nfw printer driver installed on 18.04 and printing works but scanning does not.

These instructions helped me get the printer working:

[18.04 Ubuntu Operating System does not give me a driver for Dell Mono B1160 Printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034764)

The scanner still didn't work so I tried these instructions for the scanner (Dell and Samsung seem similar, I see the term SMFP used in the Dell driver):

[Samsung scanner no longer working in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969238/samsung-scanner-no-longer-working-in-17-10)

But no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the scanner to work by following these steps:

Edit the following file:

```
sudo vi /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

Add the following two lines:

```
#Dell B1165
usb 0x413c 0x523c
```

Edit the following file:

```
sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/55-libsane.rules
```

Add the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Run:

```
sudo systemctl restart udev.service
```

Answer (score 0):

[This website](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/scanning.html) maintains Samsung drivers for Linux.

They feel their installer package is better than the Samsung official release; they offer [this help page](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/scanning.html) for scanners.